# I want to take the average price of each unique value in each month

Tags: python, date, time-series, average, feature-engineering

I am using a calendar data set for price prediction for different houses with a date feature that includes 365 days of the year. I would like to minimize the data set by taking the average month price of each listing in a new column.

```
 input data:
listing_id  date       price    months
    1       2020-01-08  75.0    Jan
    1       2020-01-09  100.0   Jan
    1       2020-02-08  350.0   Feb
    2       2020-01-08  465.0   Jan
    2       2020-02-08  250.0   Feb
    2       2020-02-09  250.0   Feb

Output data:
listing_id  date        Avg_price      months
    1       2020-01-08  90.0           Jan
    1       2020-02-08  100.0          Feb
    2       2020-01-08  50.0           Jan
    2       2020-02-08  150.0          Feb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the average price for each month using `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby("months")["price"].mean()
```

You can then create new columns:

```
for month, avg in g.iteritems():
    df["average_{}".format(month)] = avg
```

Example with dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'months':['Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar'],
                   'price':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

Result:

```
  months  price  average_Feb  average_Jan  average_Mar
0    Jan      1          2.5          1.0          5.0
1    Feb      2          2.5          1.0          5.0
2    Feb      3          2.5          1.0          5.0
3    Mar      4          2.5          1.0          5.0
4    Mar      5          2.5          1.0          5.0
5    Mar      6          2.5          1.0          5.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand me. there is a listing id column, price column and, month column. I wanted to create a average_Jan column to get the average price of each listing id in January month.

Comment: could you please provide some example data and expected output? it makes it much easier to give an accurate answer. by the sounds of it you also want to groupby listing id...?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question with input and required output data.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Dan's answer.
It may help to see another way to do this.
Additionally, if you ever have data that spans multiple years you may want a `month_year` column instead.
Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[i for i in range(121)]},
                  index=pd.date_range(start='12/1/2017',end='3/31/2018'))
df = df.reset_index()
df['month_year'] = df['index'].dt.month_name() + " " + 
                   df['index'].dt.year.astype(str)
df.pivot_table(values='price',columns='month_year')
```

Result:

```
In [39]: df.pivot_table(values='price',columns='month_year')
Out[39]: 
month_year  December 2017  February 2018  January 2018  March 2018
price                15.0           75.5          46.0       105.0
```

Comment: Thank you, That what I wanted but with an average price for each listing. I edited my question with a sample.